# How could we draw the surface?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, surfaces

I want to draw the solid that has volume equal to $\int_0^3\int_0^2 (9+x^2+y^2)\,dx\,dy$

Then volume of a surface $z=f(x,y)$ under the region $D$ is the double integral of $f$ over $D$, right?

So we we have to draw the surface $z=9+x^2+y^2$ under the region $[0,3]\times [0,2]$ ?

But how could we draw that surface?

Comment: [Elliptic paraboloid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paraboloid).

Comment: I would say "over the region", not under it.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Set $x^2+y^2=r^2$ and plot $z=9+r^2$ in 2d, then revolve.